# Customer login not working after Data migrated from Magento 1.5.1.0 to 2.3.1

Tags: migration, magento2.3.1

I recently migrated customers from Magento 1.5.1.0 to 2.3.1 then my magento 1 customers are not able to login getting error like:

```
Error : The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily.Please wait and try again later
```

sometime bellow error also

```
 Error : 'Invalid login or password.'
```

I tried to upgrade customer has using command but also getting error like

```
php -f bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade
Error :Notice: Undefined index: 0:1 in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 198
```

**anyone have idea how to fixed this ?**

Comment: I get same error but website_id is propulated correctly.. any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after lots of debugging finally, I got issue actually website_id is null in **customer_entity** table so while Magento tries to authenticate customer it throws an exception "No such Entity..." so customer login not working and it shows an error. so I just assign website id and issue fixed .

Answer (score 0):

I found the command called 
`customer:hash:upgrade` I think this will help you.

If you have many many customers if might be good to run the command with
`-d memory_limit=-1`

So, the command would be like: 
`php bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade` 
or the version with unlimited memory 
`php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade`

I hope that will help